# Почему не работает код для итерации нескольких списков?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
word_list_none = ['ладно']
    x = ['ладно']
            for x in enumerate(word_list_none):
                print("sdsda")
```

Вывод программы всегда: **sdsda**, даже если в переменную word_list_none, записано другое значение, можете подсказать в чём проблема?

Comment: Так а где здесь сравнение? У тебя просто итерация по списку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в цикле никак не используете `word_list_none`, а выполняете принт константной строки одной и той же.

`enumerate()` возвращает индекс и значение, так что скорее всего имелось в виду что-то вроде:

```
for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
  if value == another_list[index]:
    print(value)
```

Comment: А если я хочу сравнить несколько списков, по типу enumerate(my_list)?

Comment: @Миша надо понимать, что такое "сравнить несколько списков". Если имеется в виду сравнить все 1-ые элементы всех списков, все вторые и т.д. до конца (если списки одинаковой длины), то достаточно добавить нужные сравнения `if first_list[index] == second_list[index] && second_list[index] == third_list[index]` и т.д.

Comment: @Миша почитайте про циклы, про if. Это, так сказать, база.

Comment: Я про них читал, но просто те способы которые я пробовал, почти всегда не работали в моих случаях

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно сравнивать соотносящиеся по индексу элементы списков, то можно организовать сборку двух списков в `zip()`-объект и потом, вытаскивая из него значения, сравнивать их.

К примеру, вариант сравнения списков с выводом индекса и состава сравнения:

```
word_list_none = ['ладно', 'прохладно', 'холодно']
x = ['ладно', 'жарко', 'холодно']

# Случай, когда не совпадают
print([[idz, v] for idz, v in enumerate(zip(x, word_list_none)) if v[0] != v[1]])
# Случай, когда совпадают
print([[idz, v] for idz, v in enumerate(zip(x, word_list_none)) if v[0] == v[1]])
```